# d3: render new circle using slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js

I have to render three circles according to the data (longitude & latitude). I want to draw new one circle on each value of the range slider (values are from 1 to 3). It means when I have the value of slider 1, I need to have only the first circle and it has to be placed on the first location from data (longitude & latitude). When I change the value to 2, then I need to have two circles (first circle has to be kept and the second circle has to be shown according to the second longitude & latitude, etc...

When I am updating each value of the slidre, I am receiving all the three circles on the correct locations but all in the same time.

Here is my code:

```
circles: function  (){

  let data = [
  {longitude:13.41053,latitude:52.52437},
  {longitude:9.17702,latitude:48.78232},
  {longitude:8.80777,latitude:53.07516}
  ]

 let projection  = this.projection;

  let svg = d3.select(".ti").append("svg")

  let circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx",function(d) { return projection([d.longitude,d.latitude])[0];})
  .attr("cy",function(d) { return projection([d.longitude,d.latitude])[1];})
  .attr("r",9)
  .style("fill", "red")
    },
  }

<input
  id="input"
    type="range"
    min="0"
    max={this.max}
    step="1"
    value={this.node.sum}
    onClick={this.circles.bind()}/>
```

Comment: you need to `Array.filter()` your data before you use it in your `.data()` call. Remove all existing circles first.

Comment: I filtered like this( is that what you meant?) let new = data.filter(function filter_by_value(d) { if (input == 3) {  return true } });  What do you mean about removing all existing circles first?

Comment: `svg.selectAll("circle").remove();` and `var newData = data.filter( (d,i) => i < sliderValue);` or `i+1<sliderValue`

Comment: perfect! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to remove the `circle` elements from the DOM when they are no longer needed. Just like you use the `enter` selection method to create virtual elements in the DOM, you use the `exit` selection method to remove them. You can read more [here](https://d3indepth.com/enterexit/#exit).

I would do something like this:

```
// Join data
let circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data)

// Remove unwanted circles
circles.exit().remove()

// Create circles
circles
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx",function(d) { return projection([d.longitude,d.latitude])[0];})
  .attr("cy",function(d) { return projection([d.longitude,d.latitude])[1];})
  .attr("r",9)
  .style("fill", "red")
```

A toy example:

```js
// Select the SVG container
const svg = d3.select('#canvas')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 50)
  .attr('height', 50)
  .style('border', '2px solid black')

const slider = document.querySelector('#slider')

let data = [{
    x: 13,
    y: 38
  },
  {
    x: 32,
    y: 25
  },
  {
    x: 28,
    y: 17
  }
]

const renderCircles = (n) => {
  // Slice data array
  const newData = data.slice(0, n)

  // Join data
  const circles = svg.selectAll('circle').data(newData)

  // Remove circles from DOM
  circles.exit().remove()

  // Enter circles in DOM
  circles.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
}

function updateCircles() {
  renderCircles(slider.value)
}

renderCircles(slider.value)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>D3.js Slider Circles</title>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="1" min="0" max="3" step="1" oninput="updateCircles()">

  <div id="canvas"></div>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer was helpful, consider accepting it :)

Comment: Could you help me to solve this problem: when I change the value of the slider into the right side I want the tower of the balls increasing into the top. The same way when I change the value of the slider into the left side I want those balls to decrease accordingly. https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#XGAXYG